# bitmap to two dimensional array mapping error

Tags: c#, bitmap, mapping

So I have one connection to a camera but I am pulling data at multiple locations in the code. By data I mean the current frame.
My plan is to display the 8 scale version on a (Aforge) videoSourcePlayer, so the user can zoom in and out and draw a box around the area they want, but then map that to a two dimensional array of 12 byte data.
I am having a problem with the mapping,  somehow when I draw the box on the videoSourcePlayer  the corresponding pixels location are not the same in the two dimensional array and I am not sure why.
Furthermore, when I do a zoom in, the x and y values became negative numbers and I do not know how to map that back to my two dimensional array.
Now this code works for I do everything as a bitmap:

```
 private Bitmap Andrew()
    {
        Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(videoSourcePlayer.Width, videoSourcePlayer.Height);
        Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap);
        Bitmap originalBmp = videoSourcePlayer.GetCurrentVideoFrame();
      while (originalBmp == null)
        {
            originalBmp = videoSourcePlayer.GetCurrentVideoFrame();
        }
        g.DrawImage(originalBmp, videoSourcePlayer.imagex, videoSourcePlayer.imagey, videoSourcePlayer.imgWidth, videoSourcePlayer.imgHeight);

        return tempBitmap;
    }
```

but when I try to do the two dimensional array my locations are off.

and again I do not know how to handle the negative numbers when it comes to zoom in and out .

here is my code :

```
    public double[,] GetSnapshot()
    {
        global_x = 0;
        global_y = 0;
        int rawImageSize = DetermineRawImageSize();
        byte[] temp = new byte[rawImageSize];

        float[] parameters = new float[1];
        parameters[0] = 1.5F;
        transfer.bits = new byte[getBufferSize()];
        FrameDescriptor frameDesc = new FrameDescriptor();
        //gets frame from camera
        ReturnCode rc = Api.GetNextFrame(m_hCamera, transfer.bits.Length, transfer.bits, ref frameDesc);
        int i4 = 0;
        int value2 = 0;
        global_y = (int)(videoSourcePlayer.imgHeight - videoSourcePlayer.imagey);
        global_x = (int)(videoSourcePlayer.imgWidth - videoSourcePlayer.imagex);
        double[,] returndata = new double[global_x, global_y];

        for (int x = (int)videoSourcePlayer.imagex; x < global_x; x++)
        {
          for (int y = (int)videoSourcePlayer.imagey; y < global_y; y++ )
            {
                int value = ((transfer.bits[i4] << 8) + transfer.bits[i4 + 1]);
                value2 = (value >> 4);
                returndata[x,y]= value2;
                i4 = i4 + 2;
            }
        }
        return returndata;
    }
```

but when I try and map it to the video player, so the user drawing a blue box on the video player and get the pixels locations of the box, the mapping are not matching up  :

```
    double zoomingetback(int i2)
    {
        double answer = 0D;
        double l = 0D;
        double tempD = 0D;
        double[,] data = GetSnapshot();

            for (int x = stIRList[i2].X; x <= endIRList[i2].X; x++)
            {
                for (int y = stIRList[i2].Y; y <= endIRList[i2].Y; y++)
                {
                tempD = data[x, y];
                answer = answer + tempD;
                    l++;
                }
            }


        answer = answer / l;
        return answer;

    }
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: Did you consider Stride?

Comment: That first code needs to use a lot more `using` statements... it looks ridiculously leaky.

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of code and without an example that is workable I can only offer a guess that might help.  It would be better if you could show how you are calling these methods and rather than a long explanation offer a working example.  But that aside:

I think you might be off on your initial assignment of global_x and global_y variables in the GetSnapshot method.  You mention that your coords end up being negative and I think you may need to rethink the assignment of

```
global_x = (int)(videoSourcePlayer.imgWidth - videoSourcePlayer.imagex);
```

I am not sure what you really want in global_x but later you are using it as a loop limit and with this assignment I don't see how it would ever come out positive.

Comment: what do you mean by an example ? what kind of example do you need?

Comment: You give code for three methods but no examples of the values they are given/operating on.  I can't do much analysis on your code except by reading it and imaging what values the code is working on.  I realize though, that you cannot provide an example image so not sure what more can be done.  did you try what i suggested or was i wrong?

Comment: The function called Andrew() works and it used the same variables. what do you think Global_x and global_x should be?

Comment: do you know how this ling workings ?      g.DrawImage(originalBmp, videoSourcePlayer.imagex, videoSourcePlayer.imagey, videoSourcePlayer.imgWidth, videoSourcePlayer.imgHeight);

Comment: If you are asking me if I know how graphics.DrawImage works then yes I have used it before.  Not exhaustively but I have used it.  You simple provide an image, and then the drawing dimensions and location.  The issue I would think is more the values you are passing to the call, not if the call works.